# Why does Stack rebuild some dependencies on each build?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hakyll

I'm now learning hakyll static site generator with stack.

When I execute `stack build` in the directory of my Hakyll site to rebuild `site.hs`, stack also rebuilds and copy/register dependencies each time, as shown below:

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.6.5, Git revision 24ab0d6ff07f28276e082c3ce74dfdeb1a2ca9e9 (5514 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0
$ grep -Ev '^[[:space:]]*#' stack.yaml | uniq

resolver: lts-11.4

packages:
- .

$ stack build
haddock-library-1.4.5: configure
haddock-library-1.4.5: build
haddock-library-1.4.5: copy/register
pandoc-2.1.2: configure
pandoc-2.1.2: build
pandoc-2.1.2: copy/register
pandoc-citeproc-0.14.3: configure
pandoc-citeproc-0.14.3: build
pandoc-citeproc-0.14.3: copy/register
hakyll-4.12.1.0: configure
hakyll-4.12.1.0: build
hakyll-4.12.1.0: copy/register
... and site.hs.compilation ...
```

This is odd to me, because I have never changed those packages.
The rebuild takes quite long even for very small changes on `site.hs`.

Why does stack rebuild those packages? And is there any way to reduce this rebuild time?

Thank you.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. (1) Is there anything else specified in your `stack.yaml` other than the resolver? If so, please [edit] the file into your question. (2) Just to make sure: only the four packages mentioned in the console output you posted get rebuilt, right?

Comment: Thank you duplode.
(1) I fixed stack.yaml. This stack.yaml is generated one while I'm doing hakyll tutorial and contains lots of comments.
(2) Yes, stack recompile 4 additional packages. I have tried this on completely new hakyll project now. stack is now compiling these 4 additionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a discussion of this here https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3899 .  It's a known issue triggered by newer versions of haddock using sub-libraries.  There's a PR open fixing the issue, but it hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for their merge.